# Do Access-Control-Request-Headers need to be in bot OPTIONS and following request?

Tags: html, ajax, reactjs, api, cors

So I got CORS enabled on my server. OPTIONS successfully confirms the following request, lets say `[OPTIONS] /ping` with all it's headers. Then I do `[GET] /ping` and on my localhost all works, on server not as much.
So my question is, do I need to include the access headers in all of the follow up requests too?
Also, to add, I got port 8080 for the API and 3000 for the react app on my localhost. Both server urls are on port 443 (HTTPS).

Answer (score 0):

> do I need to include the access headers in all of the follow up requests too?

Yes.

The response to the OPTIONS request grants permission to make the "real" request.

You still need to grant permission to read the response to the "real" request.